# Ispell suggested word window too small

Tags: window, ispell

When I use `ispell`, it suggests replacements for misspelled words in a window at the top of the screen. However, it is too small, and I can barely read the words it contains.

How do I increase the size of the "suggestions" window?

I'm using Emacs in GUI mode. Currently, I primarily use it on my work MacBook (Mac OS Mojave) but I believe I've observed similar results in Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: `minibuffer` refers to a different animal in Emacs jargon.  You have a small window size containing a buffer with ispell suggestions and that window is what you wish to increase in size, not a minibuffer.

Comment: By "I can barely read the words it contains" are you meaning that the **font size** is too small?  The spelling suggestions should be the same size as the text in most of your other buffers?

Comment: My font size is the same, but the words are cut off. I'm guessing it's something about my font size being increased but the window size not compensating for that?

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't able to reproduce the issue, but perhaps it's specific to the Mac build.  A recipe to recreate this starting from `emacs -Q` would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customize the variable `ispell-choices-win-default-height`, which has a default value of `2`.  The doc-string states:

```
"The default size of the `*Choices*' window, including the mode line.
Must be greater than 1."
```